# getting name from features created inside a feature union

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

i am trying to get the the feature name from different classes (doing different type of transformation) passed inside a feature union that i defined myself. For example i have a bunch of emails and i want to apply the two transformation `NameLengthTransformer` and `DomainLengthTransformer` for getting the length of the name and domain. After defining `EmailTransformer` i want to also retrieve in a list the feature name defined inside `get_feature_names` so afterwards i can create a dataframe with the corresponding feature name.

```
import re

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion

def get_email_name(email) -> str:
    return email.rsplit("@", 1)[0]


def get_email_full_domain(email) -> str:
    return email.rsplit("@", 1)[1]


def get_email_domain(email) -> str:
    full_domain = get_email_full_domain(email)
    domain = full_domain.split(".")[0]
    return domain


def get_text_length(text) -> int:
    return len(text)


class NameLengthTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X.apply(lambda x: get_text_length(get_email_name(x))).values.reshape(
            -1, 1
        )
    
    def get_feature_names(self):
        return "name_length"


class DomainLengthTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X.apply(lambda x: get_text_length(get_email_domain(x))).values.reshape(
            -1, 1
        )
    
    def get_feature_names(self):
        return "domain_length"


class EmailTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.email_transformer = FeatureUnion(
            [
                ("name_length", NameLengthTransformer()),
                ("domain_length", DomainLengthTransformer()),
            ]
        )

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return self.email_transformer.fit_transform(X) 
    
    def get_feature_names(self, X, y=None):
        return self.email_transformer.get_feature_names() 

emails = pd.DataFrame({'email':['ladsf@gmail.com', 'pertro@gmail.com']})

EmailTransformer().fit_transform(X=emails['email'])
EmailTransformer().get_feature_names(emails['email'])
```

by doing this i get this output :

```
['name_length__n',
 'name_length__a',
 'name_length__m',
 'name_length__e',
 'name_length___',
 'name_length__l',
 'name_length__e',
 'name_length__n',
 'name_length__g',
 'name_length__t',
 'name_length__h',
 'domain_length__d',
 'domain_length__o',
 'domain_length__m',
 'domain_length__a',
 'domain_length__i',
 'domain_length__n',
 'domain_length___',
 'domain_length__l',
 'domain_length__e',
 'domain_length__n',
 'domain_length__g',
 'domain_length__t',
 'domain_length__h']
```

and my expected output would be to have something like this

```
['name_length', 'domain_length']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very bad way for transforming your features. The best approach is to use Pipelines instead of a simple chain of transforms. A pipeline allows you to easily combine many transformations into one single object which makes it easier to understand what exactly happens during training or prediction time. In addition, it's more flexible since you can add new steps without having to rewrite all other parts of your code. Here is an example how you could do it with a pipeline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class NameLengthTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin): def fit(self, X, y=None): return self def transform(self, X, y=None): return X.apply(lambda x: get_text_length(get_email_name(x))).values.reshape( -1, 1 ) def get_feature_names(self): return "name_length" class DomainLengthTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin): def fit(self, X, y=None): return self def transform(self, X, y=None): return X.apply(lambda x: get_text_length(get_email_domain(x))).values.reshape( -1, 1 ) def get_feature_names(self): return "domain_length" class EmailTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin): def __init__(self): self.email_transformer = Pipeline(steps=make_email_transformer()) def fit(self, X, y=None): return self def transform(self, X, y=None): return self.email_transformer.fit_transform(X) def get_feature_names(self, X, y=None): return self.email_transformer.get_feature_names() emails = pd.DataFrame(emails) EmailTransformer().fit(X=emails, y=None) EmailTransformer().get_feature_names(emails, None)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please stop posting long python code fragments entirely on a single line.